# Proper use of OBJECT tag in IE8

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, applet

```
<object classid="clsid:8AD9C840-044E-11D1-B3E9-00805F499D93" 
   id="digApp" name="digApp" width="0px" height="0px" 
   codebase="http://java.sun.com/products/plugin/autodl/jinstall-1_4_1-windows-i586.cab#version=1,4,1">
   <param name="archive" value="digitalSignature/DigitalSignatureApplet.jar">
   <param name="code" value="GUI.DigSigApplet">
   <param name="mayscript" value="yes">
   <param name="scriptable" value="true">
</object>
```

I used the tag above to identify a class in a JAR file.  However, Apache complains: **File does not exist: C:/Users/johndoe/Documents/Aptana Studio Workspace/MyApp/digitalSignature/DigitalSignatureApplet.jar/GUI/DigSigApplet.class**  The tar file exists, but apparently the concatenated filename is wrong.

Any ideas how to correct this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<object id="digitalSignatureApplet" name="digitalSignatureApplet" 
    width="0px" height="0px" tabIndex="-1"  
    classid="clsid:8AD9C840-044E-11D1-B3E9-00805F499D93" 
    codeBase="https://java.sun.com/update/1.6.0/jinstall-6u16-windows-i586.cab#Version=1,4,2" 
    type="application/x-java-applet" >
  <param name="codebase" value="/digitalSignature/" />
  <param name="archive" value="/digitalSignature/DigitalSignatureApplet.jar" />
  <param name="code" value="GUI.DigSigApplet" >
  <param name="mayscript" value="yes">
  <param name="scriptable" value="true">
</object>
```

This worked for me.